# Shouldn't "Apple" in the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ (all sites) have "Ask Different" as title?

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-button

Indeed, shouldn't all sites have uniform names in places that refer to them?   "Apple" could certainly be used parenthetically in the site tagline or description, but there should be a single site name.

Comment: There are other sites that are reported with a name that is not seen in the site itself, such as [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com), which is reported as "Cooking"; [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), which is reported as "Webmasters"; [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), which is reported as "WordPress."

Comment: I think the *purpose* of the site is more useful in that list than it's name, which doesn't convey any meaningful information.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: webmasters.SE and wordpress.SE at least have the same keyword in both titles.  The confusing part about "Ask Different" vs. "apple.SE" is that it's not at all obvious they're related, especially if you're not _that_ familiar with the Apple marketing slogan that the fancy name is based on. (And yes, that goes for "Seasoned Advice" too.)