# Use site name instead of domain name in hot questions

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox, hot-questions

In the hot questions box (top left corner thingy), it shows which site the questions are from by showing the domain name below them. I recently [suggested that English Language Learners change their domain to something like englishlearners.stackexchange.com instead of ell.stackexchange.com](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252/more-descriptive-url) to make this more meaningful, but one of the comments pointed out that when we link to sites, we should use the full name anyway, instead of the URLs.

So, can we change the hot questions to show the site name instead of URL?

For example, change:

> **Expression for "running/getting out of somewhere really fast"**
>
>   ell.stackexchange.com"

To:

> **Expression for "running/getting out of somewhere really fast"**
>
>   English Language Learners

Comment: Similar, though implemented already: [Shouldn't "Apple" in the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropDown™ (all sites) have "Ask Different" as the title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131222) (which, by the way, gives you the official name of the top left corner thingy).

Comment: Unfortunately, some SE sites have silly/undescriptive names. For example, cooking.stackexchange.com is a lot clearer than "Seasoned Advice".

Comment: @interjay If the sites with silly names progress out of beta, they'll get domain names that are just as silly (see: stackoverflow.com, superuser.com, serverfault.com..).

Comment: But cooking *is* out of beta. As are gaming ("Arqade"), stats ("Cross Validated"), apple ("Ask Different"), judaism ("Mi Yodeya"), etc. Are the domain names for all sites going to change?

Comment: It looks like SE changed their policy about top-level domain names, so sites out of beta *can* get one, but it's not being pushed as hard as it used to be, and they want them to be useful: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/

Comment: @interjay and Brendan: For sites with "silly names", we (Stack Exchange) own the URLs and they serve as redirects. The primary will always be a something.stackexchange.com, but the vanity URLs are used for swag and promoting purposes (seasonedadvice.com, arqade.com, etc.).